# How to crawl a hashtag on twitter automatically with search api

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-search

I've created an app on twitter, and i can make a search and get results.
For example when i searched #starbucks it has found 25.000 tweet but max paging limit
is 100 record per page that means i have to navigate 250 page to insert theese tweets
to my database. 
Twitter returns nextpage QueryString  its fine so, results like this

1. tweet
2. tweet
3. tweet
   ...
   99.tweet
   100.tweet

next page starts from 101 to 199..

i tried meta refresh to navigate automatically, after post form next page link
comes to meta refresh url http://example.com?q=#starbucks&count=100&max_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx/">

and 60 secs after open next page, this process continue until last page.

my question is how can do this on linux with cronjob (vps,vds or hosting)
i can make request for first page, because form working with get request, but
can linux navigate pages automatically?

thank you.